# Why isn't on event loading in Ionic 2?

Tags: angularjs, ionic2

I have a method in my `home.ts` file;

```
launch(url) {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {

        alert('hello');

        let ref = new InAppBrowser(url);

        ref.on('loadstart').lift(() => {
           alert('foo');
        })
    });
}
```

The purpose of which is to run an `addEventListener` when a certain URL is clicked.

The `alert('foo')` is being completely ignored. I thought this is how Ionic handles this with an `on` method ([see docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/inappbrowser/)).

I'm very new to mobile development including tools like Ionic and Angular. I mostly do PHP so sorry if my questions are a little basic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onPageLoaded` as I see in the docs:
http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/

so basically in your class of your component (home or any other) you can do something like this:

```
export class AnyPageOrComponent {
  constructor() {
    // Your constructor code here.
  }

  onPageLoaded() {
    alert('foo');
  }
}
```